# Adding a project to a solution using relative path

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I my winforms solution I have a main project and some library code that I added by right clicking solution and choosing Add -> Existing Project.

This works fine, but the *Project Folder* path is absolute so that every time someone checks out a copy of the code the build will break and the project must be removed and re-added to the solution.

Is there a way of adding an existing project to a solution as a relative path?

Edit: Screen shot requested:

[image]

Comment: if you copy project files under the solution directory then add, vs may recognize as relative path.

Comment: I tried moving my library code folder into my main project folder, but the path was still absolute when i re-added the project.

Comment: how do you determine it's relative or absolute?

Comment: When the project is added, i select it in the solution explorer get the "Project Properties" where two things are listed, the Project File and the Project Path. The Path is listed as "C:\MyProject\LibraryCode\" instead of "..\LibraryCode"

Comment: If I delete the project and check out a new copy to C:\MyProject2 and try to compile, I will get an error saying "Cant find "c:\MyProject\LibraryCode", which of course is now located in "c:\MyProject2\LibraryCode"

Comment: can you upload a screen capture?

Comment: @LeiYang I added a screen shot

Comment: your property windows is like showing a file's property, in my vs it is a page showing application/build/debug tabs and settings.

Comment: AFAIK the "Project Folder" entry of the properties window always shows the resolved absolute path. But you can check if the path is stored relative or absolute by opening the `.sln` file with an editor (like Notepad++ or similar) to see in what way the path to the `.csproj` file is actually stored.

Comment: It was indeed stored as a relative path. Thank you @bassfader.

Comment: Thank you @LeiYang, putting the library in the main folder worked after all! If you want to post it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: since your question does not need any code, i'm not going to answer...